# How do you remove Hypersonic from default JBoss server configuration?

Tags: jboss, hsqldb, jboss5.x

JBoss ships out of the box with the Hypersonic database.  The JNDI name is DefaultDS and the descriptor is stored in deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml.  RedHat recommends that this datasource be deleted before deploying a production JBoss instance.  RedHat does not support production instances running Hypersonic, and it is known to have the following issues:

- no isolation of transactions
- thread and socket leaks
- persistence quality
- database corruption
- database instability under load
- no support for clustered environments

So how do I remove it?

Comment: >>> Edit conf/standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml, and comment out the section Could you please define what exactly to comment out in the file?

Comment: had a less than and a greater than around the word defaults. Fixed it now, sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just removing the datasource isn't good enough as you will run into missing dependency errors:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Deployment "jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService' **
```

To cleanly remove Hypersonic with no dependency errors you must do the following:

1. Remove deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml
2. Remove deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar
3. Remove deploy/messaging (if you are not using it)
4. Remove deploy/juddi-service.sar/ and deploy/snmp-adaptor.sar
5. Edit conf/standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml, and comment out the defaults section
6. Edit conf/login-config.xml, and remove the "HsqlDbRealm" application-policy
7. Edit deploy/ejb2-timer-service.xml to comment out the database persistence policy, comment in the noop persistence policy, and change the EJBTimerServiceImpl persistence policy to noop from database

Once you have completed these steps, you should no longer get the dependency errors on startup.  However, you will intermittently see the warning below:

```
WARN  [loggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to connect to provider java:/DefaultJMSProvider, XAException.XAER_RMERR
```

To resolve this warning message you need to edit conf/jbossts-properties.xml and comment out the JBMESSAGING1 java:/DefaultJMSProvider policy

Once you've done all these steps, you should successfully have removed Hypersonic. Make sure to have done the correct steps (datasources, etc) to be using a better replacement database though :-)

Comment: I can add that if you are using JMS and don't want to remove messaging you also need the following steps:
1. Replace hsqldb-persistence-service.xml with null-persistence-service.xml
2. Add <depends optional-attribute-name="TransactionManager">jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends> to the JDBCJMSUserManagerService mbean in null-persistence-service.xml